# In MySQL version 8.0.19 how to split string into columns as some older functions are not available like character index(), string_split()

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, csv

I have one row that I would like to split into columns for example
column name is Code with the row showing 01,04,07 for product items.

I want to split up the product items into columns. Any suggestions would be helpful as I have tried the older functions but realized the SQL version I am working on does not have those options such as string_split and character index.
I used `instr()` and `substring()` but a buyer may purchase more or less items than shown above.

Comment: not sure what these "older functions" you refer to are; can you provide more information about where you have encountered them?

Answer (score 1):

Your immediate problem is your design. You should not store multiple integer values in a string column. Each tuple of values should be stored on a separate row.

As for your question: in recent MySQL version, an option is JSON. It might be handier to put the values in rows rather than in columns. Here is one way to do it:

```
select t.*, x.*
from mytable t
cross join lateral json_table(
    concat('[', t.code, ']'),
    '$[*]' columns (rn for ordinality, code_part int path '$')
) x
```

If you do want the results as columns, then one option is conditional aggregation; you need to enumerate as many columns as necessary:

```
select t.*,
    max(case when x.rn = 1 then x.code_part end) as code_part_1,
    max(case when x.rn = 2 then x.code_part end) as code_part_2,
    ...
from mytable t
cross join lateral json_table(
    concat('[', t.code, ']'),
    '$[*]' columns (rn for ordinality, code_part int path '$')
) x
group by t.id  -- assuming that "id" is the primary key of "mytable"
```

Comment: thank you. I will try JSON.